# PHP Version Compatability with Codeignitor 4

Tags: codeigniter, php-7.4

I am new to codeignitor...I have an issue of php version with Codeignitor.
The Error says

```
Your PHP version must be 7.2 or higher to run CodeIgniter. Current version: 5.6.40
```

But I have php version 7.4.3 that is shown in image below:

[image]

So whats the exact solution in your mind? share it guys with me .

Thank you

Comment: Well you know how to find your CLI Version. What version do you see when you run a phpinfo() command on a php file on your server?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw 

it says
PHP Version 5.6.40

but whats the solution of this??

Comment: if phpinfo() says 5.6.40: well, then the solution is: either upgrade/reinstall PhP 7.2 (or higher), or use Codeigniter 3.1.11